# Validating multiple dependencies within a list using Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I have a list of checkboxes that a user can select. I am saving the list using Entity Framework Code First. These are my models:

```
public class Company {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
}

public class Type {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A company has a list of types that belong to it. Some of these types depend on eachother. For example: my type with the name BMI depends on the types with the names length and weight. To enforce this I am currently using jQuery but I would like to handle it in the model. I am thinking about something like this:

```
[Dependency("BMI", DependsOn = { "length", "weight" })]
```

Is there a way to enforce dependencies within a list using Data Annotations? If there's not: what would be the best way to enforce these dependencies without having to use jQuery?

**Attempt one**

So, I started working on a solution. Here's my code so far:

```
class TypeDependencyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string Dependant { get; set; }
    public string[] Dependencies { get; set; }

    public TypeDependencyAttribute(string dependant, string[] dependencies)
    {
        Dependant = dependant;
        Dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        List<Isala.Models.Metingen.Type> list = value as List<Isala.Models.Metingen.Type>;
        if (list.Any(p => p.Naam == Dependant))
        {
            foreach(var dependency in Dependencies){
                if (!list.Any(p => p.Naam == dependency))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in my model:

```
[TypeDependency("BMI", new string {"Lengte", "Gewicht"})]
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
```

This brings me to my next problem. According to [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16710629/982517) you can't pass an array to an validation attribute. This renders my solution quite useless.

**Attempt two**

Next try, let's loose the array and do it like this:

```
[TypeDependency("BMI", "Lengte")]
[TypeDependency("BMI", "Gewicht")]
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
```

Well, you can't, according to this errormessage:

```
"Duplicate 'TypeDependency' attribute"
```

Appearently, the compiler doesn't like this either. Now, there ís another solution I can think of, but I don't like it:

```
[TypeDependent]
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
```

Attribute:

```
class TypeDependencyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        List<Isala.Models.Metingen.Type> list = value as List<Isala.Models.Metingen.Type>;
        if (list.Any(p => p.Naam == "BMI"))
        {
            if (!list.Any(p => p.Naam == "Lengte") && !list.Any(p => p.Naam == "Gewicht"))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this my only option? Can I work around this duplicate attribute error (I need multiple dependencies, BMI isn't the only one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom data annotation for you custom needs

here is are some example

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx

[How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)

Comment: I tried this, but it seems it's impossible to pass an array to an attribute. Please see my question for an update.

Comment: you cannot pass an array but you can pass multiple values. like `[Dependency("BMI","length", "weight")]`

Comment: inserted of overriding `public override bool IsValid(object value)` try to override `protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)`. bcos this has the validation context using which you can retrieve the passed values.